# how to start number each with number 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

i get data from API , i have **10** data , and i want to loop iterating number with start number **1** NOT **0**,

[image]

image above number start from zero(0), but i want to start from one(1),,

this is my code

```
   function getTopLeaderBoard() {

            getDataCall('/logpoint/top').then(function (result) {
                setCookie('user_token', result.token, 14);

                data = result.data;
                list = $('#topleaderboard-list');
                list.empty();

                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $.each(result.data, function (i, value) {

                        list.append(
                            '<ons-list-item modifier="longdivider" onclick="changePage(\'igniterdetail.html\')">' +
                            ' <div class="left">' +
                            '<span class="proj-textbold proj-textprimary mr-2">'+ i++ +'</span>' +
```

which `i++` from `$.each(result.data, function (i, value)`

how to start loop number from one(1) ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could just use `String(i+1)` instead of `i++`, which would effectively start the counting at 1:

```
list.append(
    '<ons-list-item modifier="longdivider" onclick="changePage(\'igniterdetail.html\')">' +
    ' <div class="left">' +
    ' <span class="proj-textbold proj-textprimary mr-2">'+ String(i+1) +'</span>' +
```

Comment: `i` comes in as a function arg. He probably shouldn't be mutating it at all for clarity, `String(i+1)` would be the most clear.

Comment: @mpen You know JS way better than I do...I answered only as a general solution.  I will take your advice.

Comment: =) `String(...)` part isn't strictly necessary but I like to cast it to avoid surprises. Bites me now and again when I try to do things like `i.padStart(...)` only to be reminded that although I'm producing a string I don't yet have one. And to avoid accidental addition when you want concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

you should change it as follows. (++ i)

```
'<span class="proj-textbold proj-textprimary mr-2">'+ (++i) +'</span>' +
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's the number displayed that you're concerned with, I would suggest adding 1 to the value in the `append` function. For example:

```
'<span class="proj-textbold proj-textprimary mr-2">'+ (1 + i) +'</span>'
```

Comment: `i` comes from an arg. He doesn't actually need to increment it at all.